# How can I revoke all assigned tokens and perform Logout in my Gmail Add-On by connecting to a non google service

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, gmail-addons, google-apps-script-addon

I am developing a Gmail Add On which is using a non-Google Service Authorization as a login. After the successful login, the user receives a JWT token which gets stored under 'PropertiesService.userProperties'.

Now I want to add a logout option to the add on which will again call an external(non-Google) API for logout. I want all session and tokens of the authorized user destroyed and the user should be taken to the Authorization card and then he/she needs to perform Authorization once again.

I have already tried to destroy all the 'PropertiesService.userProperties'  but it didn't work. Also did check the 'Class Session' of Google Apps Script, that also didn't help as well.

The flow is something like below:

**Step 1**: *Fire the contextualTrigger which tries to load the following function* -

```
function buildAddOn(e) {
  var accessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken; 
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);

  checkAuth();

  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
    .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('Addon Demo')) 
    .addSection(CardService.newCardSection()
      .addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText('Hello World')))
    .build();

  return [card];
}
```

**Step 2**: *In the above function it calls the checkAuth() function which checks the user Authorization and if the user is not authorized then takes the user to the Authorization Card. The code for checkAuth() is something like follows* -

```
function checkAuth() {
  var service = getService()
  if (service.hasAccess()) return

  CardService.newAuthorizationException()
    .setAuthorizationUrl(service.getAuthorizationUrl())
    .setResourceDisplayName("Display name to show to the user")
    .setCustomUiCallback('create3PAuthorizationUi')
    .throwException()
}
```

Comment: `have already tried to destroy all the 'PropertiesService.userProperties' but it didn't work.` Why?

Comment: Just to try whether we can end the user's session and revoke the authorizations by doing this.

Comment: I meant Why didn't it work? Or  What makes you think it didn't work?

Comment: Because my add on is then not asking for authorization again, it is not taking me for authorization as ideally, it should ask for authorization if the token is destroyed...

Comment: Is your workflow something like this? `PropertiesService.getUserProperties().deleteProperty('Credentials');
  if(!PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty('Credentials')){
     //call a function to end the session and ask the user to log in again
   }`

Comment: [Edit] your question to add the code and explanations. Comments will be deleted. See [mre] and [ask]

Comment: Thanks, @TheMaster, I have deleted the code from comment and added it to the question.. Please review

Comment: Try `service.reset()`?

Comment: Great. Added a answer. Consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can revoke authorization using

```
service.reset();
```

#### References:

- [Service#reset](https://gsuitedevs.github.io/apps-script-oauth2/Service_.html#reset)